# Unity on Linux with the Firebase plugin: WebSocket: ws_0 - could not connect

Tags: c#, .net, linux, firebase, unity-game-engine

I must have broken something. I haven't done much with this project in a while (adding a scrollview to a scene) and tried running it in the editor today but this error occurred. It's using the Firebase plugin. The plugin has no trouble on the same project on a Mac.

My guess is .Net is somehow broken but I don't know how to debug or test that. Any help would be appreciated.

Current setup:

- Elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki - Built on "Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
- Linux 4.4.0-109-generic
- Unity 2017.2.0b2

Things I tried to fix it:

- Try on a different version of Unity 2017.3.0b1 by setting up a brand new project, importing Firebase Analytics, Database, Messaging, and Auth.
- Typed "System.Net.Sockets.Socket" which all autocompleted well but ".Connect" didn't show.
- Tried on a different computer using the same OS and Unity and the same thing happened using just the Database plugin.
- Upgraded to latest Firebase Unity SDK 4.4.0
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Unity

Here is the error

```
1/24/2018 9:27:07 PM [Error] WebSocket: ws_0 - could not connect
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Network is unreachable
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean requireSocketPolicy) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.Net.IPEndPoint remote_end_point) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Firebase.Database.Internal.TubeSock.WebSocket.CreateSocket () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseLogger:LogMessage(PlatformLogLevel, String)
Firebase.Unity.UnityLoggingService:LogMessage(PlatformLogLevel, String)
Firebase.Database.Internal.Logging.DefaultLogger:Error(String, String)
Firebase.Database.Internal.Logging.DefaultLogger:OnLogMessage(Level, String, String, Int64)
Firebase.Database.Internal.Logging.LogWrapper:Error(String, Exception)
Firebase.Database.Internal.TubeSock.WebSocket:LogError(String, Exception)
Firebase.Database.Internal.TubeSock.WebSocket:CreateSocket()
Firebase.Database.Internal.TubeSock.WebSocket:RunReader()
Firebase.Database.Internal.TubeSock.Runnable101:Run()
Google.Sharpen.Thread:InternalRun()
```

Comment: do you use .net 3.5 or 4.6?

Comment: I have only ever used Runtime version Stable (.NET 3.5 Equivalent) and Api Compatibility Level .Net 2.0 in the project settings.

Comment: Well, switching to 4.6 in my 2017.2.0b2 project made it not open but switching to 4.6 in 2017.3.0b1 worked. Thank you so much!